# MySQL - Different Result to Display Latest Record of Each Group

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out the most efficiency way to retrieve the latest record of each group.

I manage to generate two different queries. But the details is slightly different.

These are `gcm_notification` records. 
There are more records exist. But now I just want to focus on one single record. From the image, we can see the `latest id = 1393` with the `flag = 1`

```
SELECT id, post_id, registration_id, flag
FROM gcm_notification
WHERE post_id = 1743
AND registration_id = "ezDCef_3ORo:APA91bG-sSjaMR9OwylrV7A0H7dvTEAfwJNYGUa3Ud5QZhNIh7-r2peLrb9H33pUs_KJkYisnsIUL4bUT1xrqffOv2jYXBB348oNgNVmLHGZrmgLFdWQiSVRfq9A8BhAGoBB0xN-aDs-"
```

[image]

Now I am trying to retrieve the latest record of each group using 2 different queries.

**Option 1:**

```
SELECT MAX(id) as latest_id, post_id, flag
FROM gcm_notification
WHERE registration_id = "ezDCef_3ORo:APA91bG-sSjaMR9OwylrV7A0H7dvTEAfwJNYGUa3Ud5QZhNIh7-r2peLrb9H33pUs_KJkYisnsIUL4bUT1xrqffOv2jYXBB348oNgNVmLHGZrmgLFdWQiSVRfq9A8BhAGoBB0xN-aDs-"
GROUP BY post_id
```

[image]

**Option 2:**

```
SELECT id, post_id, flag
FROM gcm_notification t1
    RIGHT JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(id) AS latest 
            FROM wp_spc_gcm_notification 
            WHERE registration_id =  "ezDCef_3ORo:APA91bG-sSjaMR9OwylrV7A0H7dvTEAfwJNYGUa3Ud5QZhNIh7-r2peLrb9H33pUs_KJkYisnsIUL4bUT1xrqffOv2jYXBB348oNgNVmLHGZrmgLFdWQiSVRfq9A8BhAGoBB0xN-aDs-"
            GROUP BY post_id) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.latest
WHERE registration_id = "ezDCef_3ORo:APA91bG-sSjaMR9OwylrV7A0H7dvTEAfwJNYGUa3Ud5QZhNIh7-r2peLrb9H33pUs_KJkYisnsIUL4bUT1xrqffOv2jYXBB348oNgNVmLHGZrmgLFdWQiSVRfq9A8BhAGoBB0xN-aDs-"
GROUP BY post_id
```

[image]

As you can see, the Option 2 display the correct result.

This is my question, 

Why **Option 1** displays the correct `id` but the `flag` value is wrong? Is it because `MAX` only update the current `id` but not the flag?

-- *Sorry if the SQL Query is too messy and hard to read because I don't know how to highlight syntax.* --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chosen of nonaggregated columns is indeterminate, which is why the first query is not correct.

## MySQL manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. ***`In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.`*** Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which value within each group the server chooses. Disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

Comment: This is the explanation that I am looking for!

Thank you for highlighting.